# The accurate time latency for 'lw' instruction in a single-cycle datapath

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture, processor

I want to calculate the cycle time of a single-cycle datapath. Then from the course, I know the time should be the execution time of the longest instruction, which is 'lw' in MIPS.
So I try to calculate the time latency for 'lw'.

I think the longest path/time for 'lw' woud be:

```
PC -> I-Mem -> Read-Reg -> ALU -> Data-Mem -> Mux(to select Mem to Register) -> Write-Reg
```

(In the path, I think `the mux to choose read-register1 or write-register`, `sing-extend for immediate value` and `mux to choose read-data 2 or immediate value` are all ignored, since the circuits are in parallel, they would take less time than other parts in parallel.)

But when I tried to find some solutions, there are some different answers, but none are identical to mine.

Someone said, the time/path should be:

```
PC -> I-Mem -> Read-Reg -> Mux(choose the input of ALU) -> ALU -> Data Memory -> Mux(select Mem to Register) -> Write-Reg
```

And some other versions:

```
PC -> I-Mem -> Read-Reg -> ALU -> Data Memory -> Mux(select Mem to Register)
```

But without `Write-Reg`

I really don't know which is really the right answer. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: If you do bypass forwarding, write-back isn't part of the critical path latency.  IDK if that's usually done or not for a non-pipelined implementation.

Comment: There are several ways to do a single cycle processor for a given ISA. And the actual answer depends on the actual traversal time of the components. Without a schematic and these times, there is no way to give a definite answer.